# How To Select All Child Rows

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I have a table with Id,Name and ParentId, like this

```
Id      Name      ParentId
----+----------+---------
 1      jijo        0
 2      arjun       1(Id)
 3      dijo        2(Id)
```

when I write a **condition Id=3** ,I want to get **all the child rows**. 
I try many codes, but unlucky....

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `view_master_data_child_rows` //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `view_master_data_child_rows`(IN SearchID INT) 
  DECLARE ParentId INT DEFAULT SearchID;

  IF ParentId != 0 THEN
    SELECT `ParentId ` INTO ParentId FROM master_data WHERE `Id` = ParentId;
    CALL view_master_data_child_rows(ParentId);
  END IF;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Plz include what are you tried and sample data expected output too.

Comment: It is a recursive hierarchical query. Based on your sample data, there are no child rows for `id = 3`. Please add expected output also to the question.

Comment: Go through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/2469308

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya that code works well, when i put my child id i will get all the parrents. but I want the reverse result, ie when i put the parent id I want all the childs

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A Can you prepare a SQL Fiddle ? Please share the link once done. I will try.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b861626/3

Answer (score 0):

Try Self Join

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name,B.ID, B.Name
FROM master_data AS A
LEFT JOIN master_data AS B ON A.Id = B.ParentId
WHERE A.Id = 3;
```

Comment: it returns only one row